# Why is foo=bar different from foo= bar?

Tags: shell, variable, assignment

What is the interpretation of the whitespace in this command `foo= bar` ?

Why are `foo=bar` and `foo= bar` interpreted differently

Example (Ubuntu bash)

```
developer@1604:~$ foo=bar
developer@1604:~$ foo= bar
The program 'bar' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install bar
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is syntax: Bash variables get inititalized with the value that follows immediately after the assignment operator `=`. That's simply the way it is...

When you do `foo= bar` then you are assigning an empty string to the variable `foo` and then execute the command `bar`.

Comment: Note that such assignment to `foo` will remain valid only for the duration of `bar`, and doesn't affect further commands in the session.

Answer (score 4):

When you do `foo= bar` then you are assigning an empty string to the environment variable `foo` and then execute the command `bar`. It can be used to pass environment variables to a new execution.

### Why it is different

Space is the delimiter character (used to separate things): adding a space makes it be two things `foo=` and `bar`. The first is an assignment, the second is telling bash to find a file and execute it. The first is optional so you will usually only see the second. The second is not optional: If you only see an assignment, it does something slightly different, it assigns to a shell variable (not an environment variable, unless preceded with `export`).

Answer (score 2):

In shell linux/unix command, when you're typing `foo=bar`,  you put the string bar in the `foo` variable. For checking you could type `echo $foo` that should return `bar` this is what  the variable `foo` contains

When you're type `foo= bar` with the space, the shell interpreter put nothing, in the foo variable and handle bar as a application command through the PATH variable. As the shell didn't find bar command in the PATH variable and you're using Ubuntu distribution looks like, the system is asking if you want to install the bar application. It's just a pop up message when you application is not find. You could check the PATH variable with this command  : `echo $PATH`. More info about this system variable [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

Answer (score 2):

`foo= bar` : before executing the command `bar` , assign  `foo` to empty. The correct way is `foo=bar` No space after the variable name and the assigned value.