# bash appear on top of my terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, path

I don't know why but since this morning, I have the complete bash path in my terminal, every time I open it. I don't know how to remove it?

thanks

```
bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.opam/system/bin: No such file or directory
```

[image: terminal]

Comment: I guess you messed up your `.bashrc` when adding a new location to PATH.

Comment: Check your startup scripts for `PATH= …`. The right syntax for setting a variable requires `=` to have no adjacent space.

Comment: Related: [Why is `foo=bar` different from `foo= bar`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/386351/108618)

Comment: @ilkkachu  I'm guessing an addition, like `PATH= "${PATH}:/new/dir"`

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, asdf, yes, of course that works too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an error message from your `~/.bashrc`. `bash` is trying to find a command with that name, and is failing.
Check your `~/.bashrc` you probably have a <kbd>Space</kbd> after an `=`, which is disallowed.